# Python adding items to lists?

Tags: python, list, python-3.3

When I add an item to a list `list.append()` or `list.insert()` or any other method when I load the file back up the item I added to the list is not there. Also I would like the list in another file just in case it made any difference.

Code:

```
User = ["pig"]
Pass = ["ham"]
User.insert(len(User)+1, "cow")
Pass.append("beef")
```

I know how to get things from other files.

Comment: http://www.mentalfloss.com/sites/default/legacy/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/400pancake_bunny.jpg

Comment: First request: please don't capitalize your variable names; conform to Python style guidelines.  Second request: please restate your question, it makes very little sense.  When you say "load the file back up" do you mean run your Python script again?

Comment: What code are you using now to load your lists from a file? Have you got any code that *saves* the list after you altered it?

Comment: If you want to save python variables to disk and then come back later and mess with them again, you may want to learn the pickle module.

Comment: or json ... or ast.literal_eval ... or a hundred other methods ...

Comment: It is evident that you lack experience with programming languages, which is fine. We might be able to provide better guidance if you describe the goals of your script. Then we might understand whether it would be best to save to a file, use `pickle`, or perhaps suggest a different solution that keeps your variables in memory in a longer running Python process.

Answer (score 1):

```
try: #load list from file if it (the file) exists
   my_list = json.load(open("my_database.dat"))
except IOError: #otherwise create the list
   my_list = []
...
#save list for next time ..
json.dump(my_list,open("my_database.dat","wb"))
```

is one of many ways to do this

you could also use pickle

```
try: #load list from file if it (the file) exists
   my_list = pickle.load(open("my_database.dat"))
except IOError: #otherwise create the list
   my_list = []
...
#save list for next time ..
pickle.dump(my_list,open("my_database.dat","wb"))
```

or do it with ast.literal_eval

```
try:
    my_list = ast.literal_eval(open("some_file").read())
except IOError:
    my_list = []
...
#save list
with open("some_file","wb") as f:
     f.write(repr(my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple data persistence between runs [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) in a good start:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pickle

def main():

    # Load the file if it exists other initialise the list
    try:
        replicating_cow = pickle.load(open("cows.p", "rb"))
    except IOError:
        replicating_cow = []

    replicating_cow.append('cow')                         # Add another cow
    print replicating_cow                                 # Print the list       
    pickle.dump(replicating_cow, open("cows.p", "wb"))    # Save the list to disk

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

After each run we get a new cow:

```
$ python replicate_cow.py 
['cow']

$ python replicate_cow.py 
['cow', 'cow']

$ python replicate_cow.py 
['cow', 'cow', 'cow']

$ python replicate_cow.py 
['cow', 'cow', 'cow', 'cow']
```

Comment: Sorry i pressed enter by accident it says  Pass = pickle.load(open("Password.p"))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface